# Call Servlet with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, servlets

- I have a Web Application consist in a simple page with 3 buttons, each of this buttons will launch a function  defined in a js: **open('size', 'code')** (the two parameters **size** and **code** are gived manually)

  ```
      <!doctype html>
      <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
        <head>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
          <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js"></script>
          <script src="step6.js"></script>
          <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <title>Step 6</title>

        </head>
        <body>


       <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">

      <button ng-click="open('lg', 1)">Click 1</button>
      <button ng-click="open('',2)">Click 2</button>
      <button ng-click="open('',3)">Click 3</button>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                   *** I WANT MY Json HERE ***

                  Foo: <b>{{foo}}</b>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </script>
      </div>
        </body>
      </html>
  ```
- in the js, **open()** is a function for call a modal window (using Bootstrap UI) the modal window have a template in the html where is defined the structure of the modal and the content inside the modal body.
- the GOAL is to launch the function **open('lg','1')** from the buttonenter image description here it will open the modal and inside the modal body will be displayed the right json passing the **"codice=1"** to the Servlet and receiving the correct json answer in the HTML body. Here there is **my js**:

  ```
          angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

          angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').factory('Service', function() {
            var Service = {
              foo: 'Shared service'
            };
            return Service;
          });

          angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $uibModal, $log, Service) {

            alert('Ctrl1');
              $scope.foo = Service.foo;
              Service.foo = 'I am from contoller 1';

              $http.get("GestioneMissioniServlet.json").then(function(response){
                  alert('JSON LOAD');
                  $scope.myData = response.data.missione;
                  });

              vm = this;
              $http.get("missioni.json")
              .success(function (response) {
                  vm.missioni = response.missioni; 


            $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

            $scope.open = function (size, codice) {

              alert('you have clicked the button:' + codice);

              Service.foo = 'il Codice:'+ codice;

              var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    myData: function () {
                        return $scope.myData;
                      }
                }
              });

              modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
              }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
              });
            };

            $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
              $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
            };

          });

          // Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
          // It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

          angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, myData, Service) {

              $scope.foo = Service.foo; //Print the code

              $scope.myData = myData;

            $scope.ok = function () {
              $uibModalInstance.close();//$scope.selected.item);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
              $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
          });
  ```
- I have a working Servlet. It works by making the request directly in the URL.
- for example when i start my servlet in Eclipse the URL will be:

  ```
  http://localhost:8180/comunicazione/GestioneMissioniServlet
  ```

and if i add the request and put a parameter between 1,2 o 3 like:

```
http://localhost:8180/comunicazione/GestioneMissioniServlet?codice=1
```

it will give to me a json file with my json inside:

```
{ "missione": {"codice":"1","descrizione":"Missione 1 missione di terra"}}
```

- What i Want: is to call this Servlet with AngularJS with (i think) $http service.

  ```
  package com.treffedin.comunicazione;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import com.google.gson.Gson;

  /**
   * Servlet implementation class GestioneMissioniServlet
   */
  @WebServlet("/GestioneMissioniServlet")
  public class GestioneMissioniServlet extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      /**
       * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
       */
      public GestioneMissioniServlet() {
          super();
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }


      /**
       * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       */
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Missione m = null;

          String codice = request.getParameter("codice");

          System.out.println("codice :" + codice);

          switch(codice){

          case "1":   m = new Missione(codice, "Missione 1 missione di terra");
                      break;

          case "2":   m = new Missione(codice, "Missione 2 missione di mare");
                      break;

          case "3":   m = new Missione(codice, "Missione 3 missione aerea");
                      break;
          }

          Gson gson = new Gson(); //istanza di Gson
          String json_missioni = "{ \"missione\": " + gson.toJson(m) + "}";
          response.setContentType("application/json");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println(json_missioni);

          System.out.println(m + " ciao");
      }

      /**
       * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       */
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

  }
  ```

  [the ng-click, launch the open() :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSCB5.png)

[the servlet after request, returns the correct json:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzUVW.png)